# Get value on select only when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select input with a few options, and a jQuery code who show a div when you select a certain option. 
At moment i'm using this :

```
$('#id_treatment_type').val() == '1'
```

It work great on chrome, but not in firefox. When I set the mouse on the option (whitout clicking) it change the value of the option.

On Chrome it work because the value change only when I clicked on the option.

The problem is that I have to put this in a loop because I have way to many fields to set a .change on everyone

```
window.setInterval(function(){alerts();}, 5000);
```

I would set this interval to a few ms because I need to show the div faster.

I need to have it work on firefox but I don't know how if someone have an idea. Sorry for my english, but I hope you could understand what i'm trying to say.

Thank you

Comment: Check out https://api.jquery.com/change/  you should be able to 'watch' for a change on the select, instead of asking for the changes every x seconds.

Comment: You don't need a loop, you just need to give these inputs a `change` event

Comment: Can you please provide a working example (with your html-markup) of what you are trying ?

Comment: _The problem is that I have to put this in a loop because I have way to many fields to set a .change on everyone_ .change (or .on('change')) applies to the select entirely, not on the options, what is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the change event. Example

```js
    $('#id_treatment_type').on('change', function(){
  alert($(this).val());
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="id_treatment_type" id="id_treatment_type">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle with a small example:

https://jsfiddle.net/usz5pyhv/

```
<select id="mySelect">  
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
</select>
<div id="whenValOne">Value is one</div>

$(function() {
    $("#mySelect").change("change", function() {
       if(this.value == 1)
         $("#whenValOne").show();
       else  
         $("#whenValOne").hide();            
    });
});
```